# Hi, I am trying to create models in Django using Visual Studio. I am running the code in interactive and get errors

Tags: django

Here are the details -

```
>>> from rntax6 import settings
>>> # settings.configure(DEBUG=False)
... 
... from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
... 
>>> from logging import NullHandler
>>> from django.db import models
>>> from django.db.models import Model
>>> class Services(models.Model):
...     service = models.CharField(max_length=255)
...     class Meta:
...         app_label = 'rntxapp6'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rabin03\source\pysrc\pyproj311\rntax6\env-rntx6\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rabin03\source\pysrc\pyproj311\rntax6\env-rntx6\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\rabin03\source\pysrc\pyproj311\rntax6\env-rntx6\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\rabin03\source\pysrc\pyproj311\rntax6\env-rntx6\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 91, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(_wrapped, name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rabin03\source\pysrc\pyproj311\rntax6\env-rntx6\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 293, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'INSTALLED_APPS'
>>> def __str__(self):
...     return self.name
...
```

The last part floors me. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have tried changing the Settings a number of different ways but get even more errors.

Comment: are you running it after `python manage.py shell` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why'd you want to do this in the interactive interpreter…?!

Comment: I think problem is in rntax6 app. Look at settings.py and look at INSTALLED_APPS, it should be a list containing installed app names.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue in your code, class Meta block and the **str** method should be indented properly inside class definition. Also, it appears that the **str** method is trying to return self.name, but there is no field named name in your model.

like this

```
from django.db import models

class Services(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'rntxapp6'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service
```

Comment: Thanks to Shlok for correcting my code. And others for useful suggestions. Because I was running my code in the interactive window I was running stand alone code. So it required importation of settings and other values. 
I found that Base_Dir was also not set. And hence I was not properly configuring these. So I am working to correct these. Thanks again.